# Error decoding JSON input via json_decode

Tags: php, json, implode

I'm writing my first web service, and I have a problem related to JSON data passing. I have my web service divided in two files: **controller.php**, which contains the service handler, and **service.php**, which contains the classes and methods to be served on request.

This is the *acquisition* fragment from controller.php:

```
    public function atender() {
        // pre-procesamos la petición
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            if (!empty($_POST["class"]) && !empty($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["function"])) {
                $clase = ucwords($_POST["class"]);
                $metodo = "{$_POST["action"]}{$this->obtenerMetodo($_POST["function"])}";
                $id = (!empty($_POST["datos"]) ? stripslashes($_POST["datos"]) : null);
```

I can attend requests on both GET and POST mode (I use GET for methods not requiring authentication, like **getCategories**, **getCategoryById**, **getProducts** and **getProductById**. These are methods to get the dish categories and dishes in a sushi restaurant.)

For any of the GET requests, everything works like expected. My problem comes when I handle POST requests. I need to get all URL parameters in JSON, as this is to serve an iOS app, and JSON is the way we handle data to/from.

This is the *processing* fragment from service.php:

```
    public function putUser($datos) {
        if (!empty($datos)) {
            $usuario = json_decode($datos);
            $this->log .= implode("/", $usuario) . "\r\n";
```

In this case, **$datos** is the JSON-encoded data from the request. It's received as **$id** in controller.php (the code above). As it's my first web service, it's very probable I'm doing something really bad here, but I'm a bit blinded.

I've tried different variations of the service handling code. Using json_decode($datos, true) doesn't work either. I get

> 'Unexpected token <' as a response and, in raw form (using the advanced REST client from Google Chrome) it says: ''Warning: implode() [`<a href='function.implode'>function.implode</a>`]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/refine/public_html/sushigo/palma/service.php on line 344'.

I know SOAP is, usually, a better alternative to writing custom code like this but, for now, I need to stick with this code and implement a better alternative for my next project. Could you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the content of the `$datos` variable? It probably isn't a valid JSON string.

Comment: I find the most common issue that screws up valid JSON are when you have your PHP warnings switched on and are getting included in the script output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says, basically, that it is NOT a valid JSON - and such error messages are usually right.

Your error is somewhere in the sending / receiving code. Probably you send the JSON in one form and try to access it in some other way. Since I have no way of looking at the requests sent from the phone, I would guess that:

- you send the data as application/json and try to receive it as an url encoded form. If you don't understand the difference, here's your problem.
- you use stripslashes on the JSON data, which is wrong. UNLESS you have magic_quotes turned on, which would also be wrong (that is: both magic_quotes and stripslashes have to go).

Comment: Stupid me... I didn't really need to perform json_decode. My coworker was sending me a string with the parameters by POST. Supposedly, it was JSON, but seems it's not. Given that, I just needed to remove any reference to json_encode, as a plain print_r($_POST["datos"]); gave me the hint. It was in array format per se, so no JSON decoding work to do here. Thanks for the hint! :)

Comment: good to hear it works :-) Still, I would check that stripslashes code. Probably all you need is ((int)$todos).